# Need to implement Watirgrid,

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, watirgrid

I want to implement watirgrid, but I'm not able to do that, every time I'm getting errors related with controller and provider starting process, Also all the example over internet, none of them are working.

Could any one please help me to implement this, a full running example with steps will be a great help.

I'm trying this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watirgrid'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

# setup a controller on port 12351 for your new grid
controller = Controller.new(:ring_server_port => 12351, :loglevel => Logger::ERROR)
controller.start

# add a provider to your grid
# :browser_type => 'webdriver' if using webdriver or
# :browser_type => 'ie' if using watir...
provider = Provider.new(:controller_uri => 'druby://127.0.0.1:11235',
                        :ring_server_port => 12351,
                        :loglevel => Logger::ERROR, 
                        :browser_type => 'webdriver')
provider.start

# connect to the grid and take all providers from it (this time only one)
grid = Watir::Grid.new(:ring_server_port => 12351, :ring_server_host => '127.0.0.1')
grid.start(:take_all => true)

# for each provider on the grid, launch a new thread to start multiple browsers
threads = []
grid.browsers.each do |browser|
  threads << Thread.new do
    p browser[:hostname]
    p browser[:architecture]
    p browser[:browser_type]
     # in this case we are starting a new IE browser
    b = browser[:object].new_browser(:ie)
    b.goto("http://www.google.com")
    b.text_field(:name, 'q').set("watirgrid")
    b.button(:name, "btnI").click
  end
end
threads.each {|thread| thread.join}
```

And Errors I'm getting is

```
DRb::DRbConnError: druby://127.0.0.1:11235 - #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could  
be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)>
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:736:in `rescue in block in open'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:730:in `block in open'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:729:in `each'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:729:in `open'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1191:in `initialize'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1171:in `new'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1171:in `open'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1087:in `block in method_missing'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1105:in `with_friend'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1086:in `method_missing'
  from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watirgrid-1.1.5/lib/provider.rb:141:in `start'
  from (irb):44
  from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):045:0>
```

Comment: It will likely help if you show some of the code you tried and the errors that occurred.

Comment: Hope this code would be enough.

Comment: I dint get any response from any one, and that made me to solve my problem, Watirgrid running successfully now. Thanks Justin

Comment: Sorry, I could not help as I have not used watirgrid. If you could add an answer on how you fixed the problem, it will help others that run into this issue.

Comment: So if you figured out what your problem was, you should provide an answer here so that anyone else with the same issue can benefit from your experience.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever figure this out, or did you have some other approach?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem, I got the provider started successfully by changing the

```
controller_uri
```

to

```
controller_uri => 'druby://machineIPAddress:11235'
```